# Why are my composer dependencies not found inside a docker container but are natively on my mac?

Tags: php, symfony, docker, composer-php, docker-compose

Within my php application, I have several dependencies which are installed via composer. When I build this application natively on my mac machine all the php dependencies are installed correctly. When the application is run the: namespaces, files and classes can all be found by composer's autoloader.

However, I wish to run this application inside a docker container, so that I can push the container up to ECS. When I run the same application (which works natively on my mac) inside a container. Composer's autoloader fails to find some class, and instead throws exceptions like this: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class ... not found in ...`.

The really weird part is that the correct namespaces show up in `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` (none missing) and the class files do exist inside the vendor directory, in the docker container.

The only solution I could find (to get composer to find the classes) is to delete the vendor's directory and re-run `composer install` all inside the docker container. But I don't want to have todo this. I should just be able to publish and deploy the container to ECS without having to install my composer dependencies again, after building. I have also tried running `composer dump-autoloader` in the entry point, but this did not resolve my issue.

Has anyone else come across an issue like this before with: php, composer and docker?

Here are some useful files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties
RUN apt-get install -y language-pack-en-base
RUN LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

# setup nginx and PHP
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y nginx \
    php7.1 \
    php7.1-fpm \
    php7.1-cli \
    php7.1-common \
    php7.1-json \
    php7.1-opcache \
    php7.1-mysql \
    php7.1-mbstring \
    php7.1-gd \
    php7.1-imap \
    php7.1-ldap \
    php7.1-dev \
    php7.1-intl \
    php7.1-gd \
    php7.1-curl \
    php7.1-zip \
    php7.1-xml \
    php-redis

# change the configuration to disable clear_env
RUN sed -e 's/;clear_env = no/clear_env = no/' -i /etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

# set up composer (we don't checksum the setup script)
ENV COMPOSER_HOME /opt/composer
RUN mkdir $COMPOSER_HOME && \
    cd $COMPOSER_HOME && \
    php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
    rm keys.dev.pub && \
    rm keys.tags.pub
COPY composer.sh /usr/bin/composer
RUN chmod 744 /usr/bin/composer

# download and install Symfony
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/bin && \
curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony && \
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony

ARG VERSION
ENV VERSION $VERSION

ENV WORK_DIR /opt/api

# copy everything to /opt/api
COPY . $WORK_DIR
RUN chmod a+x /opt/api/entrypoint.sh

# move the configuration file to the right place
RUN mv $WORK_DIR/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

# fix the permissions for nginx and PHP
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data $WORK_DIR/var && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data $WORK_DIR/app

# expose port 8000
EXPOSE 8000

# make it a working directory
WORKDIR $WORK_DIR

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/opt/api/entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
app_api:
image: app/api:latest
  command: run
  links:
    - redis
    - mysql
  ports:
    - 8000:8000
  env_file:
    - ./app/config/parameters.env
  environment:
    DB_HOST: mysql
    DB_PORT: 3306
    DB_NAME: xxx
    DB_USER: xxx
    DB_PASSWORD: xxx
    REDIS_HOST: redis
    SECRET: xxx
    ENVIRONMENT: dev
    SUBENVIRONMENT: default

mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  expose:
  - 3306
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
    MYSQL_USER: xxx
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxx
    MYSQL_DATABASE: xxx

redis:
  image: redis:alpine
  expose:
    - 6379
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case $1 in

run)
    echo "---> RUN app/api"
    echo "clear_env = no" >> /etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

    # start the PHP thing
    /etc/init.d/php7.1-fpm start && \

    # clear cache
    composer dump-autoload && \
    php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data var/cache/prod

    # start the nginx in the foreground
    nginx -g "daemon off;"

    shift 1
;;
```

composer.json

```
{
  "name": "app/api",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "crell/api-problem": "^2.0",
    "prooph/service-bus-symfony-bundle": "^0.2.0",
    "prooph/event-store-symfony-bundle": "^0.2.2",
    "prooph/event-sourcing": "^4.0",
    "prooph/event-store-doctrine-adapter": "^3.2",
    "prooph/event-store-bus-bridge": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.2",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13",
    "prooph/snapshot-doctrine-adapter": "^1.1",
    "mediamath/t1-php" : "^1.0.3",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^5.3.1|^6.2.1",
    "league/statsd": "^1.4",
    "prooph/snapshotter": "^1.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.2.1"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.0.11"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "3.1-dev"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I've glossed over much of the code here, but could it be something as simple a file permission issue?  All those files are readable?

Comment: Even when I changed the file permissions of the vendor's directory to 777 it still could not find the class.

Comment: cp -a your copied to container vendor folder (vendor_cpy).  Then compare with the composer install vendor folder (done in the container).  To discover any possible difference.

Comment: Do you need to create your /opt/api or give it perms before you copy to it in your dockerfile?  https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1295  You seem to be able to view files in vendor, so perhaps this is a red herring.  It's as if your autoloader is never registered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use following Dockerfile (fragment after php and composer installed):

`WORKDIR $WORKDIR
COPY composer.* ./
RUN composer install --no-autoloader
COPY . ./
RUN composer dump-autoload`

And add vendor/ to .dockerignore file.

I think this is preferable way to build docker images with dependencies controlled by composer, npm, yarn and similar package managers.

Comment: Why is this a preferable way to build docker images?

Comment: @Progrock :

- all build steps performed in the container, in the target runtime environment, the host machine can ever have php, composer an so on, and build results are same on any machine 

- the build context exclude large vendor dir, only source files, docker client shouldn't transfer vendor dir to docker server.